Ejecutar mysqldump desde powershell
Alguien me da una idea de como ejecutar mysqldump desde powershell?
Con este código se ejecuta pero no hace nada. El password lo tengo en el archivo de configuración my.ini, aunque se lo pongo directamente al código y tampoco funciona.
# Declare variables
$path = "d:\backups\"                      # path of backup folder
$date = Get-Date -UFormat "%Y-%m-%d"
$logFile = $path+"mysqldump_"+$date+".log"      # path of log file
$configFile = "C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.4\my.ini"           # path of my.cnf file


Write-Host $logFile

if (-NOT (Test-Path $path)) {
    New-Item -Path $path -ItemType "directory"
    if (-NOT (Test-Path $logFile)) {
        New-Item -Name $logFile -ItemType "file"

    }
   
}

 
# Set-Location $date
Add-Content $logFile "[$date]: Arrancando mysqldump"

# invoke mysqldump - insert mysqldump statement
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.4\bin\mysqldump -uroot --all-databases --defaults-file=$configFile -r $path+dbbackup$date.sql"
Add-Content $logFile "[$date]: Backup for databases are completed"

He probado a poner cmd delante de la ejecución del comando pero me manda a una consola de comandos y se queda parada.
La idea es basicamente hacer copias de seguridad diarias de las bases de datos con su log.
Ya después implementaré para que vaya borrando las antiguas.
Gracias

Use & al ejecutar el comando: & "C:\Program Files\MySQL\....

Bueno al final de esta manera funciona:

# Declare variables
$path = "d:\backups\"                      # path of backup folder
$date = Get-Date -UFormat "%Y-%m-%d"
$logFile = $path+"mysqldump_"+$date+".log"      # path of log file
$configFile = "C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.4\my.ini"           # path of my.cnf file
$archivo_backup = $path+"BackupDB_"+$date+".sql"


if (-NOT (Test-Path $path)) {
    New-Item -Path $path -ItemType "directory"
}

if (-NOT (Test-Path $logFile)) {
        New-Item -path $logFile -ItemType "file"

}

if (-NOT (Test-Path $archivo_backup)) {
        New-Item -path $archivo_backup -ItemType "file"

}

$comando = "mysqldump --result-file=$archivo_backup --log-error=$logFile --all-databases -uroot -pCONTRASEÑA" 

Invoke-Expression $comando

Gracias de todas maneras
Lo que si me gustaría saber que bases de datos del sistema debo guardar para una correcta recuperación.
Esa será mi próxima lectura, las bases de datos del sistema
